# jQuery UI switchClass, open/close same div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

this is my first question here.

I have a problem with jQuery switchClass. 
I have a div (I'll call div A) that when I click it, it changes the html text and open another div (I'll call div B). When I re-click div A I want close the div B and re-change the html text on div A.
I managed to do this but when I click again div A no longer opens the div B.
This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button_menu").click(function(){
        $('.menu_contatti').show();
        $('.button_menu').html("So già cosa ordinare....");
        $(this).switchClass("button_menu","button_menu_close");

    $(".button_menu_close").click(function(){
        $('.menu_contatti').hide();
        $('.button_menu_close').html("Non conosci il menù? Clicca qui");
        $(this).switchClass("button_menu_close","button_menu");
        });
    });
});


<div class="input1 button_menu">html text</div>

<div class="menu_contatti" style="display:none;">....</div>
```

Comment: `switchClass()` isn't part of jQuery core but jQuery UI, i added the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to use `.toggle()`. see demo below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.divA').on('click', function() {
        $('.divB').toggle();
        if($('.divB').is(':visible')) {
            $('.divA').html('Close');       
        }
        else {
            $('.divA').html('Open');  
        }
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divA">Open</div>
<div class="divB" style="display:none;">This text show and hide</div>
```

also, as a note, if you prefer to use classes instead of `.toggle()`, you should use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`